# Modify Dropzone configuration for each individual file

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone.js, dropzone

In Dropzone, I want to set different "resizeWidth" value for each separate Image depending on Image type.

Basically, For "JPEG" => 1000 and "PNG" => 750

Following is my code,

```
$(function(){

    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;  

    var eproductDropzone = new Dropzone("#postMedia", {

        url: "upload.php",      
        chunking: false,              
        autoProcessQueue: false,    
        maxFilesize: 6,                 
        acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.jpeg",

        resizeWidth: 1000,  

        sending: function(file, xhrObj, formData){   //  Runs before sending each file

            if(file.type == "image/png"){

                eproductDropzone.options.resizeWidth = 750;
            }else{   //  "image/jpeg"

                eproductDropzone.options.resizeWidth = 1000;  
            }
        },

        queuecomplete:function(){   

            alert('All Files upploaded successfully.');
            eproductDropzone.options.autoProcessQueue = false;  
        }
    });

    $("#upload").on("click", function(){

        eproductDropzone.options.autoProcessQueue = true;  
        eproductDropzone.processQueue();        
    });

});
```

If I log "resizeWidth" value its getting changed but Dropzone still executing the first value.

Comment: The moment you are checking the file type is probably to late.

The Sending function runs "before sending the file" not before "uploading the file", which probably means the resize is already applied

Comment: I also tried "accept" function. But its not working too. The "resizeWidth" value is getting changed but Dropzone is executing the value which is defined first. Can you suggest any other way to achieve what I want ?